# Is there a way to get ifttt to trigger from wind forecast?

Tags: triggers, weather-api, ifttt

I am trying to create a good wind surfing alarm so I want to create an ifttt rule that takes wind *forecast* and emails me if the wind is going to be greater than (say) 10 mph.

I can create a rule in weather underground that does this for the *current* conditions...but I can't find anything that will cause a trigger if wind forecast is > X mph for the next saturday after today...or even more simply, but not ideal, just email me if tomorrow's wind is going to be > X mph.

I've searched for windfinder & ifttt; bbc weather (I'm UK based) & ifttt, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to try windy.com and its mobile application to receive the notifications you are looking for.